# Set input value by VueJS and mixing the content of value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I try this:

```
<input type="text"
    name="username"
    v-model="user.name"
    :value="'The user name is: '+user.name">
```

Is possible somehow to show in the input filed is "The user name is: John Doe" ?

Or I need definitely use a computed value in this case?

Comment: you can use a placeholder

Comment: can you show me a code for this?

Comment: since you are using v-model the placeholder text will not be displayed until the input field is empty . Sry for that, but what is the exact usecase you are expecting because you dont want to display the username is in the username input field right?

Comment: I use this solution in a contracting form, which has a previous product selection Vue template. The user select the product, set up parameters, and click on "Next" button, and here I show a form with disabled fields and uploaded the previously selected values. He can give name, email, etc, and asking a call back from the employee. So what I want is just a summary page (what is a form too).

Comment: Anyway... I implemeted with computed values... just now I have "myval" and "text_myval" named values too... not a nice one.

Answer (score 2):

The options seem to be to either bind directly to the value, instead of a v-model, or to created a computed property and v-model to that:

https://codepen.io/aprouja1/pen/jwxagE

```
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data(){
    return{
      user:{
        name:'Bob'
      }
    }
  },
  computed:{
    nameString(){
      return `The user name is: ${this.user.name}`
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for (I think) it a little bit confusing because you're basically saying you want the textbox to contain text like "The user name is: Bob" but you want `user.name` to equal "Bob" even after the user edits the textbox value to some text which may not even begin with "The user name is: ".

Realistically the text "The user name is: " should not be in the textbox at all, it should be a `<label>`:

```
  <label>The user name is:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" v-model="user.name">
```

You can also use CSS to create your own custom "input" element which contains a `<label>` and an `<input>` element with all styles removed so it looks like the text "The user name is: " is part of the editable text but actually isn't.

Comment: Actually I'm not saying that :) I have a data model `data.user.name` and it is updated from somewhere else. I just want to show `The user name is {{ user.name }}` in the field. All the thext needs to be in the input field value.

Comment: In that case, all you need to do is remove the `v-model` and just use the `:value` binding.